# Ignore local changes to PDF files during pull

Tags: git

Questions have been asked and answered [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157189) about discarding all local changes before a git pull.

I am contributing to a shared repo hosting mainly TeX files and I am confronted with my colleagues having the despicable habit of hosting the resulting PDF too.

I would like to set up git to automatically discard local changes to PDF files before pulling. How can I achieve this ? With a hook (I never ventured in this realm) ?

Comment: I feel like the proper solution would be to remove all PDFs from the repo and add a `.gitignore` file to prevent adding any in the future. This way the issue is solved once and for all.

Comment: This is what I would do. But it will not fly with my colleagues…